# Adding a dynamically generated page as a partial view in an AngularJS app

Tags: node.js, angularjs

I'm currently learning Node.js and AngularJS. To learn how to develop with these technologies, I've been playing with the Phone Catalog sample app found [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-phonecat).

The thing I can't figure out is, how to include a server-generated page in my views. Everything I see with Angular seems to be related to static .html. However, I would like a dynamic page that includes some code that's generated on the server. In other words, I would like to add something like

/app/partials/dynamicPhone

Is this even possible? For the life of me, I can't figure out how to add a server-side page as a partial.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

AngularJS don't differentiate between server-generated pages, and static pages. From browser's perspective it's all the same.

Just use your `/app/partials/dynamicPhone` as you would use a static template - only remember you can't use any query parameters with it (because it's supposed to be "static" ie. not changing)